# Is an array of one boolean in Java smaller than a standalone variable?

Tags: java, memory-management, boolean

My searches on SO have failed me, so if this is a duplicate, please redirect me.

With that out of the way, my question: I learned, from experience and browsing SO that a Java `boolean` is stored as a 32-bit `int` if you declare it as a standalone value, but as an 8-bit `byte` if you declare it within an array. My question, here, is as follows: **Which is more memory efficient? Does the meta data of the array make it bigger in memory than the alternative?**

```
boolean oneVariable = false, oneArray[] = {false};
```

Comment: Isn't that comparing apples and pears? The first has value semantics, and the second has reference semantics. Pick the one you *need*.

Comment: It's comparing memory management techniques, so like tangerines versus clementines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "meta data" of the array includes:

- 8 bytes (32-bit JVM) or 16 bytes (64-bit JVM) for object header
- 4 bytes (32 bits) for the length of the array

Add on the 1 necessary byte for the boolean data and you have 13 bytes (32 bit) or 21 bytes (64 bit) at a minimum.

However, objects are allocated memory in 8-byte multiples, so even though you only need 12 or 20 bytes of overhead + 1 byte for the boolean, you'll end up using 16 or 24 bytes of memory, respectively, for your array object.

In addition to the 16/24 bytes the object itself will take up, you'll need 4 bytes (32 bit) or 8 bytes (64 bit) for the memory address of the object, totaling 20 or 32 bytes of memory, respectively, to store your boolean in an array.

The size of a standalone variable is JVM dependent.  Java does not specify the size of storage, and in fact [Oracle says](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

> This data type represents one bit of information, but its "size" isn't something that's precisely defined.

Older JVMs use a 32-bit stack cell, used to hold local variables, method arguments, and expression values so a single boolean used as a variable would consume 4 bytes; making the array at least 5 times as expensive as for a single boolean.  This answer may be different if, for example, the boolean is a class variable in which case it would just be a single byte added to the existing overhead.  In newer JVMs a single boolean would only use 1 byte, but depending on its context and the 8-byte padding necessary to align memory addresses, could still consume up to 8 bytes of heap space.  It would still be smaller than the boolean array.

Comment: The 4 extra bytes are for the length.

Comment: We really shouldn't repeat falsehoods here: A boolean only uses a single byte (why should it use 4 bytes?) In HotSpot so it's 16 times less efficient.

Comment: @voo Not so much a falsehood as a JVM-dependent value. How about you expand on the answer and correct it, instead of telling me I'm lying?

Answer (score 7):

The Array is an actual Object that comes with a memory penalty (I believe 12 bytes)  So the primitive boolean is smaller.

Comment: All Objects have 4 bytes for wait/notify, and 4 bytes for something else (not sure what).  An array also has 4 bytes for the length.  So 12.  As Daniel noted, this size is rounded up to a multiple of 8.  So the "12 bytes" I mentioned is really 16.

Comment: It has a reference to the class data structure this is 32-bit or 64-bit depending on the JVM. (You have to know what type the object is) An array has the "field" length which is 4-bit long. and there is 4-bytes for other things which include the object monitor.

Comment: Also all objects are created on an 8 byte boundary. i.e. they always reserve a multiple of 8 bytes.  If that sounds in-efficient its worth nothing that 64-bit C & C++ have an 16 byte alignment. ;)

Comment: @Peter Lawrey I was wondering if some of the space was for the class info.  Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 1):

As [user949300](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8959335/387852) mentioned, all objects carry a penalty that make them larger than primitives.  For only a single boolean though, memory doesn't really matter.  If you are storing a large number of booleans, consider using a [BitSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html).  I believe under the hood it uses approximately 1 bit per boolean (plus some overhead).

Comment: For this thought experiment, it's a single `boolean`.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue029.html) Java specialist article is a good source for understanding the *memory* usage.